# Prestashop stock management - multiple warehouses

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop

I'm testing the shop on localhost , ps version 1.5.4.1, using the basic theme.
It's a clothing store that has branches in several cities, so every store should have its own stock.
I created a warehouse for every store, set the available quantities for products and its combinations based on warehouse stock.

My question is how do I know, when a client is buying a product from the online store, from which warehouse does the product get subtracted, how does this system work? can I configure this? 
If there is a possibility to select the warehouse source of the product on delivery?

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a warehouse for a product for a specific shop the advanced stock management feature takes care of quantity for all the warehouses. At this moment you can't see, in an order, from which warehouse the quantity is subtracted.

It will be available in a forthcoming release.

Best regards.